# OpenSCAD library for empty space/holes

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, openscad

I am working on a design in OpenSCAD, and need (would want) two things that seem tedious to hand-code:

1. A pattern of holes in a wall, for less weight/material. Could be round holes or some geometric pattern.
2. Empty enclosed space, with some grid-structure for stability. Again, for saving weight/material (and time during the printing).

Are there any libraries for these things?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of libraries that do that for you (but you can create your own, see end of the answer), but creating a relieve hole pattern is not that difficult or tedious using [iterator functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Conditional_and_Iterator_Functions) (e.g. the `for loop`). Note that it may not be a good idea to make enclosed holes inside your object, see the bottom section "Internal cavities in models" at the bottom of the answer.

Small OpenSCAD test script:

```
 tol=0.2;
 
 difference(){
   cube([100,100,10]);
   for (x=[10:20:90]){
     for (y=[10:20:90]){
       translate([x,y,-tol/2]){
         cylinder(r=9,h=10+tol,$fn=180);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

[image]

This can be used for both parts of your question, but in case the pattern needs to be inside an object you need to lower the value of `h` in the subtracting cylinder and raise/translate it (you could use the `center=true` in the `cylinder` function as a parameter and raise the center to the middle of your object `translate([x,y,objectThickness/2])`). You could make a [`module`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/User-Defined_Functions_and_Modules) of the recurring pattern yourself to create your library.

note: Replace `cylinder` with `cube` or any [other geometrical solid](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids) or (2D) pattern (use `linear_extrude`) to subtract from your part.

---

### Internal cavities in models

Note that it is not always wise to create your own spacing/grid structure enclosed in the model. Please read the accepted answer of [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/182/why-do-some-models-appear-broken-in-slicing-software). This answer explains that slicer applications work best with true solids!

---